# Do not know how to implement this MVC pattern

Tags: python, django

I have a `JS` module (a bunch of interface code). Let's call it `mymodule`. It is located at `myapp/modules/mymodule`. I want to keep together `urls.py` and `views.py` associated with this module. In other words I want to somehow reference `myapp/modules/mymodule/urls.py` from my root `myapp/urls.py` and not to cram my root `myapp/views.py` with all those handlers associated with `mymodule`. So, this is what I tried by now:

```
## myapp/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp import views

urlpatters = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    ... a lot of other urls
    ... and now I want to include urls associated with mymodule
    url(r'^mymodule/',include('myapp.modules.mymodule.urls'))
]

## myapp/modules/mymodule/urls.py
from myapp.modules.mymodule import handlers

urlpatters = [
    url(r'^dosomething/',handlers.dosomething)
]

## myapp/modules/mymodule/handlers.py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def dosomething(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world!")
```

And I want this - when a user goes to `127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/mymodule/dosomething`, he or she should see "Hello world!" message.

**EDIT**

My updated version of the code which still leads to `Page not found error` looks like this:

```
## myapp/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import *
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    ... a lot of other working urls
    url(r'^myapp/mymodule',include('myapp.modules.mymodule.urls')),
)


## myapp/modules/mymodule/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import *
from myapp.modules.mymodule import handlers

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^dosomething/',handlers.dosomething),
)

## myapp/modules/mymodule/handlers.py

from django.http import HttpResponse

def dosomething(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world!")
```

**EDIT**
My root urls.py file now looks like this:

```
## myapp/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import *
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    ... a lot of other working urls
    url(r'^myapp/mymodule/',include('myapp.modules.mymodule.urls')),
)
```

So, there is an ending slash now, but the problem is - when I go to `127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/mymodule/dosomething`, the Django debugger says that `Page not found` and that it tried just `^myapp/ ^myapp/mymodule/` pattern - so I see no mentioning of `^dosomething/` pattern. However, if I now go to `127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/myapp/mymodule/dosomething`, I now see in the debugger page that it tried `^myapp/ ^myapp/mymodule/  /dosomething` pattern. It says `/dosomething`, because I played with mymodule/urls.py and now it looks like:

```
## myapp/modules/mymodule/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import *
from myapp.modules.mymodule import handlers

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'/dosomething',handlers.dosomething),
)
```

So, I guess the reason of all these troubles is that I can't combine all these patterns together to make them work. I need clear understanding on how my url pattern should look like inside root `urls.py` and inside `myapp/urls.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `myapp` prefix to the url regex:

```
url(r'^myapp/mymodule/',include('myapp.modules.mymodule.urls'))
```

Also note that `urlpatters` should be created by the [`patterns()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.patterns) function:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
)
```

**UPDATE**: Sorry, I didn't notice that first `urls.py` is from the app.  I confused it with the project `urls.py`.  So as I understand now you should have three `urls.py`:

**project/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^myapp/',include('myapp.urls')),
)
```

**myapp/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^mymodule/',include('myapp.modules.mymodule.urls')),
)
```

**myapp/modules/mymodule/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'dosomething/', handlers.dosomething),
)
```

Comment: I will check it in a minute. Thanks!

Comment: I still get `Page not found error` when I go to 127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/mymodule/dosomething. I will now update how my code look like at this moment

Comment: Please, have a look at my updated version of the code. I still can not make it work. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to add the `/` slash at the `r'^myapp/mymodule'` regex,  It should be `r'^myapp/mymodule/'`.

Comment: Note that `patterns` is [deprecated in 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.patterns) and will be removed in 2.0. The plain list of `url` instances in the first code block is correct.

Comment: Hm, still not working, but much closer to the solution, I will now post what I get in Django debugger page. Just in a second.

Comment: Ouch. I finally made it work. I will publish the final combination. Thank you, guys!

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is what I have now. And it is working! Thank you, sir!